# Are Vue 3 third-party components retro-compatible with Vue 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have built some components that are meant to be used as third-party components (installed via `npm` then imported in a parent project) with Vue 2.

Since I plan to upgrade to Vue 3, I will need to upgrade my Vue 2 third-party components to Vue 3. I will provide `.esm` and `.cjs` in the build `dist/` output (using `main` and `module` properties from `package.json`).

However, when my third-party components will be updated for Vue 3, will they still be able to be used in Vue 2 projects? Is there some kind of retro-compatibility between the 2 versions when building third-party libraries/components?

I am building my SFC third-party components with [rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/) ([as recommended by the Vue team](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/single-file-component.html#building-with-rollup)) and some plugins such as `rollup-plugin-vue`, `rollup-plugin-postcss`, `@rollup/plugin-commonjs`, etc.

Comment: I highly doubt. There is a migration build of Vue 3 which is compatible with Vue 2 code and components - but it is intended as a temporary bridge to make the transition from Vue 2 to 3 smoother, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I'll handle different builds using different package version such as 1.X.X for Vue 2 and 2.X.X for Vue 3.

Comment: You may want to use vue-demi depending on the case.

Comment: I read that vue-demi is mostly for non-DOM components, such as Vue plugins for example. I may try to read a bit more about vue-demi and my use-case.